# iOS model designations?

Tags: discussion, ipad, ios

I have the new iPad WiFi + 4G 16gb purchased in the UK, and the model on the back is A1430, yet in the OS it refers to MD366B. When I download the iOS 5.1 IPSW file, it refers to iPad3,3_5.1.1_9B206_Restore, so this is an iPad3,3 for OS purposes.

I've seen on several websites discussing OS revisions that there are 3 versions of the iPad 3, the WiFi only, WiFi + CDMA (or sometimes Verizon), and WiFi + GSM (or sometimes AT&T).

They talk about the GSM version being either 3,2 or 3,3. I assume this is a mistake on the sites.

So what is the best way to refer to the models, and why are there 3? Hardware model, iOS model, and IPSW model.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would refer to them via the general model information:

- iPad 3 Wi-Fi Only
- iPad 3 CDMA
- iPad 3 GSM

Distinct enough, no?

Information about the region+carrier only if relevant.

Comment: Or if you are suitably masochistic: `The New iPad WiFi`, `The New iPad CDMA`, etc. :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why there are so many ways to refer to the models though? That's just adding a 4th method :)

Comment: I'm sure model numbers make sense to Apple and the carriers, but with other users (us), not as necessary.